# Scheme: Update a list without using imperative features like set

Tags: scheme, quicksort

I have only just started to learn scheme and were asked to implement the quick-sort algorithm in scheme, but we are not allow to use any imperative features like `set!` and we are not allowed to use `filter`

I have tried to come up with my own algorithm with this in mind, but I can't seem to avoid the use of `set!` for updating a list:

```
(define quicksort
(lambda (L)
    (cond
        [(or (null? L) (null? (cdr L))) L]
        [else (let ((pivot (car L)) (small '()) (large '()))
                   (do ((i (- (length L) 1) (- i 1)))
                       ((= i 0))
                           (if (< (list-ref L i) pivot)
                               (set! small (cons (list-ref L i) small))
                               (set! large (cons (list-ref L i) large))))
                           (append (quicksort small) (list pivot) (quicksort large)))])))
```

This code works, but is there any way of updating the lists `small` and `large` without the use of set?

Answer (score 3):

If you cannot use `set!`, you cannot mutate lists. You are being asked to do this functionally, without any mutation. Instead of modifying a list in-place, build up smaller, partially-sorted lists and then combine them while preserving the sort.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I've solved my issue now with a recursive partition function  :)

Answer (score 1):

To be fair Quicksort is an in place algorithm and many would state replacing the vectors with lists will change it enough to no longer bee quicksort. I'll ignore this at the moment.

Split large stuff in smaller chunks of code. This way you can test each step:

```
(segment 5 '(5 1 1 3 8 6 4 9 8 5 3 5 3 8 6))
; ==> ((1 1 3 4 3 3) (5 5) (8 6 9 8 8 6))
```

Of course you make the simple tests first:

```
(segment 5 '(5)) ; ==> (() (5) ())
(segment 5 '(5 1)) ; ==> ((1) (5) ())
(segment 5 '(5 8)) ; ==> (() (5) (8))
(segment 5 '(5 8 1 5)) ; ==> ((1) (5 5) (8))
```

The order of the results in the sub list is not important. eg. the result `((3 3 4 3 1 1) (5 5) (6 8 8 9 6 8))` is equally as sufficient and most probably easier to do.

With that made `quicksort` by first checking if it is a less than 2 element list eg. `(or (null? lst) (null? (cdr lst)))` and return the argument or create the 3 segments using the first element as pivot and then `append` the recursion of the lesser and the higher and then appending the 3 lists together and you have them in order.

As inspiration here is a procedure that splits on odd? and not:

```
(define (split-odd lst)
  (let loop ((lst lst) (odd '()) (even '()))
    (cond
      ((null? lst) (list odd even))
      ((odd? (car lst)) (loop (cdr lst) (cons (car lst) odd) even))
      (else (loop (cdr lst) odd (cons (car lst) even))))))
(split-odd '(1 2 3 4 5 6))
; ==> ((5 3 1) (6 4 2))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer helped me come up with my own way of solving this issue! :)